# how to send GET request with parameter

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm building a simple MEAN application, but facing some problem with a GET method.

I inserted some data in my mongo collection, now I want to GET all results passing it's Id as parameter, but angular is returning me the following:
[image]

I've searched about headers and httpParams, but can't seem to find a solution.
I tested on postman as well, using Get and passing a body as JSON, and it worked, I'm facing trouble sending it's body from angular

here's my code:

Angular service

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class WebService {
    public api = "http://localhost:3000/";
    //NODE API
    public getRate(param: any){
      console.log(param);
      return this.http.get(this.api + "api/rate", {_id: param})
    }
}
```

NodeJs function

```
        module.exports.countVotes = function(req, res) {

        console.log(req.body._id);

        VoteModel.find({movie_id: req.body._id}, (err, rate) => {
            if(err){
                console.log('rate not found', err)
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'failed to get movie rate'
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200).json(rate);
                console.log(rate);
            }
        })
    }
```

Node returns me req.body as undefined when called.
What am I missing? please someone help me.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters, https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Comment: GET requests don't have a body.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because GET requests don't have request body. You can try use POST request with request body or pass the id to GET request as request param or as path variable.

Answer (score -1):

You must pass an instance of HttpPrams in http.get -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class WebService {
    public api = "http://localhost:3000/";
    //NODE API
    public getRate(param: any){
      let params = new HttpParams().set('_id', param);
      console.log(param);
      return this.http.get(this.api + "api/rate", { params: params })
    }
}
```